# Google Computer Engine Firewall for DNS

Tags: dns, cpanel, google-compute-engine, whm

I have two GCEs on the same internal network, each with their own external IP Address.
I have the following firewall rule for their shared network .

allow-bind-udp  0.0.0.0/0   udp:53  Apply to all targets
default

DNS works fine for one but not the other, even with firewalld off it still does not work. In fact it would appear that none of the firewall rules work for the other GCE.
So what am I missing.
The rules are for the network not a single GCE.
SO I am thinking this should just work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the bind service running on the machine and listening on port 43?

```
lsof -iUDP
```

if it is running, can you send the output from below commands for both instances:

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

and the fw list:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, found the problem to be pebkac, IP assignments had been changed, not that I remember ever doing them, but some how when I created an App Engine it took that GCEs IP address and I never noticed.

Answer (score 0):

From VMs perspective, firewalls are used to control the incoming traffic. When using DNS, it's an outgoing traffic targeting udp:53 of the DNS server. And as far as I know, you don't need any firewall to be able to use DNS.

I suggest you run the following commands and paste the output in the question:

`gcloud compute networks list`

`gcloud compute firewall-rules list`

`gcloud compute routes list`